# what is the problem for Heap corruption at the end of programin in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

There is a problem in my simple program about heap corruption I unfortunately could not understand. this error happens when program ends

program is about reading a binary of specific length and split it to sub-packet then initialize a proper parser for each sub-packet and save all of parser in a deque

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#182) at 0x005F2270. CRT
>   detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.

```
int main()
    {
        deque<uint8_t> testData = { 0, 115, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100 };
        deque < shared_ptr<IParser>> parsers;
        Splitter test(testData, parsers);
        test.split();
    }
```

the Splitter class

```
struct Splitter {
    const deque<uint8_t>& input;
    deque<shared_ptr<IParser>>& parsers;
    long x = 0;
    Splitter(const deque<uint8_t>& input, deque<shared_ptr<IParser>>& parsers) :input(input), parsers(parsers)
    {

    }

    deque<shared_ptr<IParser>> getParsers();
    bool split() {
        deque<uint8_t> newVec;
        auto headerparser = make_shared<HeaderParser>(newVec);
        parsers.push_back(headerparser);
        return true;
    }

};
```

the IParser class

```
struct IParser {
        const std::deque<uint8_t> input;
        IParser(const std::deque<uint8_t> input):input(input){} 
    };
```

and finally HeaderParser

```
struct HeaderParser :public IParser
{
    shared_ptr<Header> output;
    HeaderParser(const deque<uint8_t>& input):IParser(input)
    {
      uint8_t* buff = (uint8_t*)&output;
      for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Header); i++)
         buff[i] = 0;
     }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  uint8_t* buff = (uint8_t*)&output;
```

This line is wrong. You are not converting `Header` pointer to `uint8_t*`, but rather the whole `shared_ptr`. You overwrite memory in `shared_ptr` and possibly beyond. `shared_ptr` then tries to remove itself, but you broke it.

You can extract object pointer from `shared_ptr` by using `get()` method (remember to check if it is not `nullptr` before using it).

```
  uint8_t* buff = (uint8_t*)output.get();
```

Comment: completely right, I changed it recently output from a simple header and forgot about this line, Thanks a lot @Yksisarvinen